# LibCURL sends filename rather than file contents when I try to upload a binary file in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, upload, libcurl, php-curl

I'm getting this weird behavior with libCURL. When I try to upload a file by appending "@" to the beginning of filename (as documented in libCURL's man page), instead of file contents being uploaded, libCURL sends the filename itself (with the @ in the beginning).

This is running on Windows 2008 R2, with xampp version 5.6.8, which has curl compiled in (curl version 7.40.0).

Here's releant code fragment:

```
$post['pic'] = "@C:\\image.png";

$ret = curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE );
if (!$ret) die("curl_setopt CURLOPT_POST failed");
$ret = curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post );
if (!$ret) die("curl_setopt CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS failed");

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

This code works on Linux but not Windows Server 2008.

Here's the form data that I get:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; \\
boundary=------------------------c74a6af8b52d997a

--------------------------c74a6af8b52d997a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pic"

@C:\image.png
--------------------------c74a6af8b52d997a--
```

As you can see I receive `@C:\image.png` rather than contents.

Does anyone know why libCURL wouldn't upload the file contents?

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation of [curl-setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

> CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation.
>   To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The
>   filetype can be explicitly specified by following the filename with
>   the type in the format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be
>   passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as
>   an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value
>   is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to
>   multipart/form-data. As of PHP 5.2.0, value must be an array if files
>   are passed to this option with the @ prefix. As of PHP 5.5.0, the @
>   prefix is deprecated and files can be sent using CURLFile. The @
>   prefix can be disabled for safe passing of values beginning with @ by
>   setting the CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD option to TRUE.

The behavior depends on php release and @ prefix is now deprecated.

You should use [CurlFile class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) to set the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS of the curl request like this :

```
$post['pic'] = new CurlFile('C:\\image.png');
$ret = curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post );
```